# Get errors when I try to build image from dockFile

Tags: docker

I made a dockerFile, when I try to run **docker build -t testDocker . --no-cache** , I get following errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://211.76.113.82:80/data/053e3163532a4b0d/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/readline/libreadline7_7.0-3_amd64.deb  Redirection loop encountered
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y software-properties-common' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Here is my dockerFile :

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER jimmy

#install nginx
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common 
RUN apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get install -y php7.1 php7.1-fpm
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
```

Can anyone tell me why is error happen?

Comment: From the error, you fail to fetch the whole image.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT How is that happen? I change nothing, But after a few minute,  I try to run again, then it work successfully.

Comment: Sometimes, there is something strange we cannot understand. Maybe you can try `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the Dockerfile, well there is but nothing that would cause the build to fail. I built the image using your dockerfile locally and it works.

Try this:

Rename dockerFile to Dockerfile

Run:

```
docker build --no-cache -t test .
```

Your problem is you put --no-cache in the wrong place, it needs to be before the `.`

Also you should update your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER jimmy
#install nginx
RUN apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y software-properties-common php7.1 php7.1-fpm nginx
```

Comment: Let me know if it fails

Comment: This issue seems weird cause it only happen on yesterday, I will tell you when it happen again, thanks man!